# Detecting Surface touchpad gestures in Delphi

Tags: delphi, gesture, touchpad

When using Chrome on my Surface Pro, I can zoom web pages in and out by using the zoom gesture on my touchscreen or on the touchpad.

I'm looking into adding similar zoom functionality to my Delphi application. I figured out how to respond to touchscreen events (either using Delphi's "interactive gestures" support and `OnGesture` events, or using Windows' [WM_GESTURENOTIFY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353243(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WM_GESTURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353242(v=vs.85).aspx) events), but touchpad events don't seem to generate any gesture events?

What interface or API should I be using to see touchpad gestures?